# Counting cell data without Holiday & Weekend

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas, array-formulas

I want to count only without color cell, which is indicated the working day And color cells was Holiday & Weekend.

My Counting formula:

`{=SUM(--NOT(ISNUMBER(IF(WEEKDAY(DATE($A$2,$A$3,OFFSET($A$5,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)),2)<=6,OFFSET(A8,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31),0)))--NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(DATE($A$2,$A$3,OFFSET($A$5,0,31($A$3-1)+1,1,31)),HolidayList[Date],0))))+COUNT(OFFSET($A$5,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31))-31}`

Please anybody help me about issue, i was failure to try this

For better understanding the Attachment link was below

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2n3BIKH9iL5OFM3YmRHT2xpYkk&authuser=0

Answer (score 1):

Minhaz,

This seems a little overly complex. If you're trying to find out the number of working days in a month without holidays included, have you tried the NETWORKDAYS function? I've used it to help work out Service levels before.

`Networkdays` checks if days are mon-fri, and against a list of holidays you define. For example:

```
 Start      End     working Days                 | Holidays in 2015
01/05/15 10/05/15   =Networkdays(A1,B1,D1:D10)   |01/01/15
02/05/15 15/05/15                                |03/05/15
```

where A1 is the first date you want to check from, B1 is the last date you want to check from and D1-D10 contains a table showing the holiday dates

Hope this helps!

Comment: + for general advice, even if not applicable in this particular case (if I understood it correctly)

Comment: Dear, @Miller If you want you can check the Below link for your understanding --- 
https://doc-0g-34-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/qsrvvubv129tgjvg9uda0n185k0473gm/4g2rdvgr7m4uod5g1n2re6av5vg8oi8f/1432353600000/04156024462471415985/04156024462471415985/0B2n3BIKH9iL5OFM3YmRHT2xpYkk?e=download
And also help me for this problem.

Comment: I've not currently got access to excel as i'm not at work currently. I had assumed you were trying to work out service levels or similar by counting days. My solution is different to how you've presented it, but would save you some effort if your issue is how I've understood it. You could even use some variant of a countif or array formula to populate the table if you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to debug formulas, it might help to add new-lines with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make them more readable, e.g.:

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISNUMBER(
       IF(WEEKDAY(
            DATE($A$2,$A$3,OFFSET($A$5,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)),
            2) <= 6,
          OFFSET(A8,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31),
          0))
 ) * --NOT(ISNUMBER(
       MATCH(
         DATE($A$2,$A$3,OFFSET($A$5,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)),
         HolidayList[Date],
         0)))
) + COUNT(OFFSET($A$5,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)) - 31
```

however, it is not possible to debug your formula for other people than you - as it is very complicated, the `offset` functions are volatile, you don't have any sample data in the spreadsheet with explanation what would be the expected result and you did not provide any other hints what the formula is supposed to compute

FTR: please note the December 01 2015 is a Tuesday, not a Sunday as displayed in your spreadsheet when I opened it (I did NOT enable macros though)...

if I understand the use case correctly, I suggest you use a helper row (e.g. row 4) to insert actual date of the column, then you can use following (non-array) formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D8:NK8,
N(YEAR($D$4:$NK$4) = $A$2),
N(MONTH($D$4:$NK$4) = $A$3),
N(WEEKDAY($D$4:$NK$4, 2) < 6),
N(ISNA(MATCH($D$4:$NK$4, HolidayList[Date], 0))))
```

Comment: Dear, @Aprillion
If you want you can check the Below link for your understanding ---
https://doc-0g-34-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/qsrvvubv129tgjvg9uda0n185k0473gm/4g2rdvgr7m4uod5g1n2re6av5vg8oi8f/1432353600000/04156024462471415985/04156024462471415985/0B2n3BIKH9iL5OFM3YmRHT2xpYkk?e=download

And also help me for this problem.

Comment: I solved "the problem as I understand it". if you don't understand the solution, please ask concrete questions what exactly is not clear to you...